# GA Regex Filter - Filter PPC traffic and replace it with "PPC"

Tags: regex, google-analytics

1)  www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all

2)  www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all&cp=randomID&keyword=randomKeyword&network=randomNetwork&v3=sometype&v4=MM

So I have these 2 types of URLs being reported on my Analytics being:

1. Traffic that went on that page organically
2. Traffic that went on that page via Paid Traffic

I need to basically find all the links that have a "&" followed by (cp|keyword|v1|v2|v3|v5) after the value for “card_type” and replace it with “ppc-traffic” - so ideally would have :

1. www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all
2. www.mysite.site/product/brand/ppctraffic or just mysite.site/ppctraffic

What I attempted:

Search String
Request URI

```
^(https?:\/\/\S+\/[^?]*)(.*?)&(cp|keyword|v1|v2|v3|v5)
```

Replace String:

```
/ppctraffic
```

(I’ve also tried `$1/ppctraffic` and `$2/ppctraffic`)

When testing the regex online it seems to work so not sure what Im doing wrong.
Any help deeply appreciated

Comment: Should it be directly after `cardtype=all&cp=` or can the value `&cp` be anywhere after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to capture in a group upon  `/brand` matching not a question mark `[^?]+` and match `?card_type=all&` afterwards followed by any character until the end of the string.

As your links do not start with https:// you could make that part optional `(?:https?:\/\/)?`.

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.[^?]+)\?card_type=all&(?:cp|keyword|v[1235]).*$
```

Then in the replacement use `$1/ppctraffic`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBYmPA/1)

```js
const pattern = /^((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.[^?]+)\?card_type=all&(?:cp|keyword|v[1235]).*$/;
[
  "www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all&cp=randomID&v1=randomIDv2=productName&v3=sometype&v4=MM&fbclid=randomID",
  "www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all",
  "www.mysite.site/product/brand?card_type=all&aa=randomID&v1=randomIDv2=productName&v3=sometype&v4=MM&fbclid=randomID"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(pattern, "$1/ppctraffic")));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @The fourth birth. I did forget to add that card_type assumes different values. How can I change it from card_type=all to card_type=ANY VALUE ?

Comment: I did forget to add that card_type assumes different values. How can I change it from card_type=all to card_type=ANY VALUE ?

Comment: If it can by any word character `card_type=\w+` If you want to allow all non whitespace chars then `card_type=\S+` If you want to allow specific ones use a character class `card_type=[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: Oh great! Thanks, really appreciate it! Lets see if Analytics will filter it correctly now